# How to convert macro to counter

Tags: macros, counters

For making the following mwe work I obviously (so I thought, but that is not true, see answers) have to convert the macro `\i` to a counter. But how?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \foreach \i in {1,2,3} \Romannum{\i};
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to make it a counter, but you have to use another variable name for the loop:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {1,2,3} \Romannum{\x};
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused: Why is \x handled in a different way than \i?

Comment: The macro `\i` is already defined in LaTeX (it's a dotless i: `ı`). It can be used in a `\foreach`, but only if it is expanded at the right time, such as in the answer by @skillmon  (otherwise the original definition is used, which results in an error).

Comment: Oh yes, I remember reading about the `\i`. It never happened to produce problems in `\foreach` so far, but I will avoid it in the future. Thanks for the solution and the explanation.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to make it a counter, but you have to expand `\i` before `\Romannum`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \foreach \i in {1,2,3} \expandafter\Romannum\expandafter{\i};
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works fine, but Marijn's solution is shorter. ;-) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not very fond of `\Romannum`, which uses `\MakeUppercase`, making it unexpandable.

Here's an expandable version:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Romannum}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral#1@}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \foreach \i in {1,2,3} {\Romannum{\i};}
\end{document}
```

It could be easier doing `\let\Romannum\@Roman`, but there are `babel` languages that change `\@Roman`.

Another strategy is using `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \Romannum \int_to_Roman:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \foreach \i in {1,2,3} {\Romannum{\i};}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And it does that out of laziness it seems, which makes it relatable and worse.